# Composite Design Pattern, let child (composite) know who its parent is

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns

So I've been stuck at this for awhile now. Basically I want to let the composite component know its parent. When I tried to access the parent object in parameter, it gives me null when I try to log it, but if I try to print out the object's name, it doesn't throw me errors. Sorry for the poorly formatted code and every help will be appreciated, please let me know if there is anything I could add if the question is unclear or vague. Thanks!

This is the employee class

```
public class Employee {

   protected String name;
   protected Employee parent;

   public Employee() {
    this.parent = null;
    this.name = "name not set";
   }

   public String getName() {
       return name;
   }

   public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
   }

   public Employee getParent() {
       return parent;
   }

   public void setParent(Employee parent) {
       this.parent = parent;
      }
   }
```

This is developer class

```
   public class Developer extends Employee {
   protected ArrayList<Employee> staffList;

   public Developer() {
       super();
       this.staffList = new ArrayList<Employee>();
   }

    public void add(Employee e) throws Exception {
       System.out.println(e.getParent()); //prints null even though the parameter has parent
       if (e.getParent() instanceof Developer) {
           throw new Exception("You cannot add staff when your lead is a dev");
       } else if (e instanceof Manager) {
           throw new Exception("You cannot add manager as your staff bcs u r a dev");
       }

       e.setParent(this);
       this.staffList.add(e);
   }

   public void printData() {
       for(Employee e : staffList) {
           System.out.println(e.name);
       }
   }

}
```

This is Manager class

```
public class Manager extends Employee {
protected ArrayList<Employee> staffList;

public Manager() {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    super();
    this.staffList = new ArrayList<Employee>();
}    

 public void add(Employee e) {
     e.setParent(this);
     this.staffList.add(e);
 }

 public void printData() {
        for(Employee e : staffList) {
            System.out.println(e.name);
        }
     }
 }
```

On Main.java

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Manager man1 = new Manager();
    man1.setName("man1");

    Developer dev1 = new Developer();
    dev1.setName("dev1");
    man1.add(dev1);

    Developer dev2 = new Developer();
    dev2.setName("dev2");
    man1.add(dev2);

    Developer dev3 = new Developer();
    dev3.setName("dev3");
    dev2.add(dev3);

    System.out.println(dev3.getParent()); //composite.Developer@2a139a55

    Developer dev4 = new Developer();
    dev4.setName("dev4");
    dev3.add(dev4);
 }
```

Comment: You do not show code from where you call `Developer.add(..)` method. If it prints `null` it means it is `null` at that time.

Comment: In `Developer#add` you call `System.out.println(e.getParent());` before `e.setParent(this);`, so, of course it must be `null`... or did you set it before that in other part of the code (not posted)?

Comment: Answer updated, please take a look at the psvm :)

Comment: The problem is what I already commented before @KevinYou

Comment: Ahhh I just realized I have some logic flaw that's been pointed out by the answer below, thanks :) @lealceldeiro

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What’s missing is the calling code.  Your print statement in Developer.add() printing null indicates that you haven’t set the parent.  Check the calling code to make sure you have indeed set the parent.

A few other items to consider.  The logic in the Developer.add() method, seems a bit off.  You’re throwing an exception if the parent of the employee you’re adding is a dev.  This would indicate logic that you’re trying to ***transfer*** the employee to this developer.  Is that your intention?

I'm guessing that what you meant to say is the dev can't have employees because his boss is a dev, then that if statement should be:

```
if (this.parent !== null && this.parent instanceof Developer) throw...
```

For example, if the calling code is something like:

```
dev.setParent(new Developer());
dev.add(new Employee()); <-- throw exception "You can't have staff 'cause your boss is a dev, and not a manager."
```

Comment: Ah, that's the mistake, it works perfectly fine now, thanks a bunch!